# Why is this function not printing out the DIV like I expect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in my `render()`

```
const recentActivity = this.props.touchpointsPayload.data
  .map((array) =>
    {if (array.mdn === this.props.number) {
      console.log("WE GOT A MATCH --> " + this.props.number + " PROPS / " + array.mdn + " from response");
      if (array.sources === undefined) {
        <div>No Sources</div>
      } else {
        array.sources.map((sources) =>
          sources.events.map ((events) =>
          <div className="container-timeline righttimeline" history-type={events.source} key={events.id}>
            <div className="content-timeline">
              <h2 className="callTypeCaps">{events.tag}</h2>
              <div>{events.description}</div>
              <div>{events.date}</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          )
        )
      }
    }}
  );
```

I will then call this inside of my `return`

```
{recentActivity}
```

I get the following error.. why? Line 23 is `<div>No Sources</div>`

```
  Line 23:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

ENTIRE FILE

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';


class Activity extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        sources: []
      };
    }

  render() {

    const recentActivity = this.props.touchpointsPayload.data
      .map((array) =>
        {if (array.mdn === this.props.number) {
          console.log("WE GOT A MATCH --> " + this.props.number + " PROPS / " + array.mdn + " from response");
          if (array.sources === undefined) {
            return <div>No Sources</div>
          } else {
            return array.sources.map((sources) =>
              sources.events.map ((events) =>
              <div className="container-timeline righttimeline" history-type={events.source} key={events.id}>
                <div className="content-timeline">
                  <h2 className="callTypeCaps">{events.tag}</h2>
                  <div>{events.description}</div>
                  <div>{events.date}</div>
                </div>
              </div>

              )
            )
          }
        }}
      );

    return (
      <div id="componentBorder" className="componentBorder padding05">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 componentTitle componentDiv">Recent Activity</div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div id="scrollingActivity">
          <div className="padding1030">

            <div className="container">
              <div className="row marginLeft10">
              <div className="timeline">
                  {recentActivity}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    );
  }
}


export default Activity;
```

Comment: because you are not returning anything from map callback function. simply add return everywhere: `return array.sources.map...` and here also: `return <div>No Sources</div>`

Comment: Please show the complete class, especially the render function

Comment: added entire file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning elements, it should work like this:

```
const recentActivity = this.props.touchpointsPayload.data
  .map((array) =>
    {if (array.mdn === this.props.number) {
      console.log("WE GOT A MATCH --> " + this.props.number + " PROPS / " + array.mdn + " from response");
      if (array.sources === undefined) {
        return <div>No Sources</div>;
      } else {
        return array.sources.map((sources) =>
          sources.events.map ((events) =>
          <div className="container-timeline righttimeline" history-type={events.source} key={events.id}>
            <div className="content-timeline">
              <h2 className="callTypeCaps">{events.tag}</h2>
              <div>{events.description}</div>
              <div>{events.date}</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          )
        )
      }
    }}
  );
```

Comment: @soldfor No problem! To automatically prevent mistakes like this in the future, I'd recommend using TypeScript. TypeScript will point out that you aren't returning valid elements from your `render` method. :) Also, please mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the return statement or wrapping the element in parentheses :

With return statement ( just remember that the elmeent must be be in the same line as the return statement ):

```
const recentActivity = this.props.touchpointsPayload.data
  .map((array) =>
    {if (array.mdn === this.props.number) {
      console.log("WE GOT A MATCH --> " + this.props.number + " PROPS / " + array.mdn + " from response");
      if (array.sources === undefined) {
        return <div>No Sources</div>
      } else {
        array.sources.map((sources) =>
          sources.events.map ((events) => {
          return <div className="container-timeline righttimeline" history-type={events.source} key={events.id}>
            <div className="content-timeline">
              <h2 className="callTypeCaps">{events.tag}</h2>
              <div>{events.description}</div>
              <div>{events.date}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
           }
          )
        )
      }
    }}
  );
```

Or with parenthesis that i think it adds readability:

```
const recentActivity = this.props.touchpointsPayload.data
  .map((array) =>
    {if (array.mdn === this.props.number) {
      console.log("WE GOT A MATCH --> " + this.props.number + " PROPS / " + array.mdn + " from response");
      if (array.sources === undefined) {
       return ( <div>No Sources</div> )
      } else {
        array.sources.map((sources) =>
          sources.events.map ((events) => {
          return ( <div className="container-timeline righttimeline" history-type={events.source} key={events.id}>
            <div className="content-timeline">
              <h2 className="callTypeCaps">{events.tag}</h2>
              <div>{events.description}</div>
              <div>{events.date}</div>
            </div>
          </div> 
           )
           }
          )
        )
      }
    }}
  );
```